# FFmpeg for seamless branching Blu-ray

Tags: ffmpeg

Does FFmpeg have any support for seamless branching Blu-rays? I didn't find any articles on Google or elsewhere regarding it. Can FFmpeg have folder or playlist input so it can read an entire Blu-ray for seamless branching version?

My sole purpose is to extract tracks from bluray.

Comment: You may wish to add some additional context to this question. You can technically [concatenate files](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate) from a text list given certain conditions but more often you would likely be using a script of some sort. Likewise, you probably would be using more than just FFmpeg if you are copying anything off a Blu-ray.

Comment: How do I do that if I don't know exact list of files.